# Replace MVVM Light with MvvmCross or use both

Tags: mvvm-light, mvvmcross

We have a WP8 app which utilizes MVVM Light and it works great. However, now we want to target iOS using Xamarin. It appears MvvmCross is the better framework for cross platform development.

Does anyone have experience changing out frameworks like this? Or referencing MvvmCross along with MVVM Light?

Thanks for sharing your experiences.

Comment: This is a very open ended question - is there anything specifically you are struggling with? In general it should be pretty straight forward. You will probably need to spend some time changing the way navigation works, but apart from that you should be fine.

Comment: @RossDargan Thanks. No struggles yet - making plans for the effort to re-factor 40 View Models. Looking for any gotchas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like Ross said this is open ended however using both is fine.  You can use the bindings from MvvmCross on iOS and still keep the MvvmLight things you have implemented.

Edit: the question of which is better is open ended but I don't think the question should be closed because it is very feasible to use MvvmLight and MvvmCross (bindings) together.

This [repo](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/CrossLight) has an example of using the MvvmCross bindings only.  [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=cFsuCN-9MdQ) video has some info on it.

Comment: Thanks for the CrossLight tutorial. That helps.